# Parsec hanging when using buildExpressionParser

Tags: haskell, parsec

I’m trying to create a basic parser for math equations using Parsec, and I’m having some trouble using the `buildExpressionParser` function.

I’ve created a `parsecParse` function, but it just hangs forever when I call it in ghci: `parse parsecParse "" "200*6"`. I can’t figure out why. Any ideas?

```
module Equation where

import Control.Applicative hiding (many, (<|>))

import Text.Parsec.Char (char, digit)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator (many1, option)
import Text.Parsec.Expr (Assoc (..), Operator (..), buildExpressionParser)
import Text.Parsec.Prim ((<|>), try)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)

data Equation = Leaf Double | Tree Op Equation Equation deriving (Show)
data Op = Plus | Minus | Multiply | Divide deriving (Show)

parsecParse :: Parser Equation
parsecParse = try parseOperator <|> parseDouble

parseDouble :: Parser Equation
parseDouble = fmap (Leaf . read) $ (++) <$> integer <*> fraction
    where integer  = many1 digit
          fraction = option "" $ (:) <$> char '.' <*> many1 digit

parseOperator :: Parser Equation
parseOperator = buildExpressionParser table parsecParse
    where table     = [[ getOp '*' Multiply, getOp '/' Divide ],
                       [ getOp '+' Plus,     getOp '-' Minus ]]
          getOp c o = Infix (char c >> return (Tree o)) AssocLeft
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting problems because `parseOperator` is recursing back on itself in leftmost position, something which Parsec cannot handle directly, and which gives an infinite recursion.

The last argument to `buildExpressionParser` should be a parser that parses more "basic" elements.

It is fine to recurse indirectly on `parseOperator`, e.g. to handle parenthesized elements, but *not* such that it ends up in the leftmost position of itself.

Comment: I’m a little confused, because the examples I’ve seen[1][2] also seem to pass themselves recursively to `buildExpressionParser`. What’s the difference between what they’re doing and what I’m trying to do?

[1]: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.5/docs/Text-Parsec-Expr.html
[2]: http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2005-08-27-power-parsing-with-haskell-and-parsec.html

Comment: Given that, if I change my function to `parsecParse = char '(' *> parseOperator <* char ')' <|> parseDouble` and I call it using `parse parseOperator "" "200*6+5"` then everything works.